# Invalid index type "String" for a base of type "Array[Dictionary]"

Tags: godot, godot4

I am using mouse_click to direct the character to move to the clicked position but an error occurs

Code:

```
func get_body_under_point(point):
    var space_state = get_world_2d().direct_space_state
    var result = space_state.intersect_point(point)
    if result:
        return result["collider"]
    else:
        return null
```

The error occurs in the line return result["collider"]
Invalid index type "String" for a base of type "Array[Dictionary]"

Answer (score 0):

The method [`intersect_point`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_physicsdirectspacestate2d.html#class-physicsdirectspacestate2d-method-intersect-point) does not give you an `Dictionary`. As the error says, it gives you an `Array` of dictionaries (`Array[Dictionary]`).

This is because, there could be multiple things overlapping in that position (on that note, I remind you that you can use `intersect_point` to get areas too).

Since `intersect_point` can give you multiple results, you can iterate over them:

```
var space_state := get_world_2d().direct_space_state
var result := space_state.intersect_point(query)
for entry in result:
    prints(entry["collider"])
```

You, of course, could pick the first one:

```
var space_state := get_world_2d().direct_space_state
var result := space_state.intersect_point(query)
if result.is_empty():
    return null
else:
    return result[0]["collider"]
```

If you only want one result, you can use the second parameter of `intersect_point` to specify that:

```
var space_state := get_world_2d().direct_space_state
var result := space_state.intersect_point(query, 1)
if result.is_empty():
    return null
else:
    return result[0]["collider"]
```

*You didn't specify the type of your `point` variable, so I'll also remind you that `intersect_point` takes a `PhysicsPointQueryParameters2D`.*